# Bluetooth GPS 5Hz interface for Android

Tags: android, gps, gps-time

I hope this is an appropriate question for this group.  It is not strictly speaking a programming question unless I end up writing my own NEMA listener instead of the location listener but that would mean a start over on a lot of code.  I have written a GPS based application and want to use an external GPS at 5HZ. I have been searching for a couple of hours on Google and this forum with no luck for answers to my problem.

I have been using Android apps to talk to the external GPS.  I can get 5Hz with Bluetooth GPS Provider or GPS Mouse but they both have time errors of about 18 seconds (slow).  I can get accurate time with Bluetooth GPS but only at 1Hz.  I have checked the raw NEMA output of the Qstarz unit and it is correct at both 1Hz and 5Hz.

I am using the standard location listener and everything in the program is working fine.  I just want to get 5Hz data and accurate GPS time.  At first I thought it was a GPS Leap Second issue but the NEMA data is correct with real time.  I use WWV to find real time.

Comment: I have just figured out that Bluetooth GPS Provider does not report GPS time so the system uses the internal clock of my tablet.  Useless for my application which is a GPS clock...  I would love to know of an app that will give me 5 Hz update and report the GPS time

Answer (score 1):

Try:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bluegps4droid/files/

This app updates mock location at the frequency of the source GPS.